# Разбиение на выборки и кросс-валидация

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Скажите, у меня есть df... Если я собираюсь использовать кросс-валидацию, мне же достаточно разбить на обучающую и тестовую выборки мой df и мне не нужно дополнительно извлекать валидационный набор. Верно? Или я что-то не правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы разбиваете ваши данные на обучающую и тестовую выборки и потом применяете кросс-валидацию на этой обучающей выборке, то полученная таким образом тестовая выборка и есть "валидационный набор", на котором вы потом дополнительно сможете проверить качество обучения модели. Также это можно назвать "отложенной выборкой".

Comment: Я думал, что цель кросс-валидации, это обучение, подбор гиперпараметров и проверка качества модели...Разве на выходе есть выборка?

Comment: @ЕгорОвчинников Я, наверное, нечётко выразился. Тут надо картинки рисовать, слова всегда можно неправильно понять. Я имел в виду выборку, полученную разбиением. Обучающая выборка идёт в кросс-валидацию. Вообще, обычно разбиение ещё сложнее и валидационная выборка - это такая же тестовая выборка, но уже на внутренних шагах, например, на эпохе обучения нейросети. Цель кросс-валидации скорее проверить равномерность качества обучения на разных частях выборки. Если CV score сильно скачет на разных фолдах, то что-то нужно делать. Ну и ещё чтобы не откладывать много данных в тест CV удобна.